# Control de errores,me genera bucle infinito

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a utilizar `try-catch`. En este ejemplo pido un número y si el usuario introduce un número se visualiza, si escribe cualquier letra salta el error.

Mi intención era que al introducir una letra me salte el mensaje de `"Lo siento, has introducido letras"`, y que me vuelva a pedir el número. El problema es que me muestra el mensaje de `"Lo siento..."` infinitamente.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    boolean error;

    Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Inserte un numero: ");
            num = pedir.nextInt();
            System.out.println("El valor es " + num);
            error=false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            error=true;
            System.out.println("Lo siento has introducido letras ");
        }
    }while(error);

}
```

Comment: Mira mi respuesta, además de corregir el error con el `pedir.next()`, te propongo una forma correcta de hacerlo sin recurrir a bloques try/catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás limpiando el número mal introducido, por lo que siempre volverá a intentar obtener lo introducido la primera vez.

Para limpiar los datos inválidos debes hacer una lectura de una línea completa:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int num;

  Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Inserte un numero: ");
    try {
      num = pedir.nextInt();
      System.out.println("El valor es " + num);
      break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      /* Limpiamos la entrada incorrecta */
      pedir.next();
      System.out.println("Lo siento, has introducido letras");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      /* Nunca se captura, ver:
      https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html */
      System.out.println("Fin de la entrada de datos");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente, pero ten en cuenta que deberías comprobar si es válido el campo con `hasNextInt()` en vez de con un `try/catch`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int num;

  Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Inserte un numero: ");
    /* Comprobamos si quedan más datos en la entrada estándar */
    if (pedir.hasNext()) {
      if (pedir.hasNextInt()) {
        num = pedir.nextInt();
        System.out.println("El valor es " + num);
        break;
      } else {
        /* Limpiamos la entrada incorrecta */
        pedir.next();
        System.out.println("Lo siento, has introducido letras");
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("Fin de la entrada de datos");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: En la parte del else, al poner num=pedir.next(); me da error. Incompatible types, String cannot be convert String to Int

Comment: Error de copy/paste, el `num =` no debe estar ahí. Lo corrijo ahora.

Comment: Eso te iba a decir, que eliminando num= sale perfecto! Lo que no entiendo es la diferencia entre try/catch y hasNextInt...

Comment: Los `try/catch` detectan errores/excepciones en tiempo de ejecución y los captura para actuar dependiendo de cada evento capturado o haciendo una acción final (`finally`) si la captura también produce otra excepción. Es una mala práctica apoyarse en estas detecciones para evitar hacer controles correctos a los datos de entrada. Por ejemplo, en ninguno de los dos casos se tiene en cuenta que se reciba un `EOF`, en ambos saltaría una excepción no controlada del tipo `NoSuchElementException`. Voy a editar mi respuesta para contemplar ese caso con y sin bloque `try/catch`.

Comment: Te he modificado la respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo en el que un bloque `try/catch` que no puede capturar un error. Un `NoSuchElementException` es un *unchecked exception*. Para probar cómo se produce la excepción pulsa `Control + D` (`EOF`) o bien teclea `echo | java ejemplo`.

Comment: PD: Te he puesto una forma alternativa de salir del bucle sin usar una variable de control. Por norma general es bueno evitar desarrollar código pensando en capturar las excepciones, sobre todo en las funciones. Lo ideal sería propagarlas en su definición agregando las posibles excepciones en el `throws`, a no ser que tengas que actuar de una forma u otra porque la salida depende de ello. También es una buena práctica implementar funciones de control que te permitan anticiparte a cualquier situación de error, por eso la clase `Scanner` te proporciona `hasNext()`, `hasNextInt()`, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios! La verdad es que nos lo están enseñando en clase y según la profesora es muy importante controlar los errores! No nos enseñó nada de 'hasNext()' ni 'hasNextInt'.... de echo le pregunté que diferencia había entre controlar con estas o con try/catch y me dijo que ninguna ...

Comment: Se trata de acostumbrarse a seguir buenas prácticas. Es como usar variables para controlar la salida de un bucle infinito en vez de usar `break`, o crear una variable o instancia de un objeto dentro de un bucle en vez de definirla fuera una vez, para evitar congestionar la pila y, por ende, el recolector de basura, etc. Es muy importante controlar los errores, en esto estoy de acuerdo, pero no siempre hay que hacerlo con el bote salvavidas de los `try/catch`. **Deja que los `try/catch` te informen de problemas que no tenías previsto que se produjeran, y no de los que podrías haber evitado.**

Answer (score 3):

Solo tienes que añadir `pedir.next()` en la gestión de errores:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    boolean error;

    Scanner pedir = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Inserte un numero: ");
            num = pedir.nextInt();
            System.out.println("El valor es " + num);
            error=false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            error=true;
            System.out.println("Lo siento has introducido letras ");
            pedir.next();
        }
    }while(error);

}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Estaba ya desesperada, no sabía que podía ser! Muchas gracias :)